# Python Telethon Как ловить сообщения

Tags: python, telethon

Вот так ловятся все сообщения, Кроме сообщения чата Telegram service notification. А мне нужны сообщения, как раз от туда. Как?

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage())
async def handler(event):
    if event.is_reply:
        replied = await event.get_reply_message()
        sender = replied.sender
        await client.download_profile_photo(sender)
        await event.respond('Saved your photo {}'.format(sender.username))
```